# Java Streams: Grouping, Summing AND Counting

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

I'm new to streams but very intrigued with the possibilities.

I'm trying to write a stream that does grouping, counting and summing at the same time. The data involved is actually quite simple but writing the streaming statement I need is proving challenging and I'm not seeing anything really helpful in Google searches.

First, let me describe my data, then I'll show you how I've solved two-thirds of the problem. Perhaps you can tell me how to fit in the missing piece.

The data is ticket sales from a company that sells concert tickets. Each sale consists of an agency code, an order number, order date and the number of tickets sold. Therefore, it looks like this:

```
AgencyCode  OrderNumber OrderDate  TicketsSold
----------  ----------- ---------  -----------
TW          111111  2016-03-01          4
TW          111112  2016-03-01          2
CP          201000  2016-03-01          3
TW          111113  2016-03-01          8
CP          201001  2016-03-02          2
EL          300001  2016-03-01          4
AS          400000  2016-03-02          2
```

What I'm trying to get out of this data is a summary showing the total number of orders for each agency code and the total number of tickets sold for that same agency code. Therefore, the values I want to get for this particular set of data is:

```
AgencyCode  Orders   TicketsSold
TW               3            14
CP               2             5
EL               1             4
AS               1             2
```

I've got the grouping working and also the number of tickets sold. It's just the counting of the orders that I'm trying to get.

Here's how I got the tickets sold by agency:

```
 Map<String, Integer> salesByAgency
     = ticketOrders.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TicketSale::getAgencyCode,
                 Collectors.summingInt(TicketSale::getTicketsSold)));
```

`TicketSale` is the class that holds a single ticket order. My collection, `ticketOrders`, is a `LinkedHashSet` holding a bunch of `TicketSale` records.

How do I adjust what I have to get the number of orders for each agency code?

Comment: What about `x -> 1`instead of `TicketSale::getTicketsSold`?

Comment: Thanks Yassin for fixing my little tables. How do you make the textbox respect the line-feeds?

Comment: Aventurin, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm still very new to both lambdas and streams.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Map<String, Integer> orders = ticketOrders
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TicketSale::getAgencyCode,
                                 Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
```

or

```
Map<String, Long> orders = ticketOrders
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TicketSale::getAgencyCode,
                                 Collectors.counting()));
```

to get the number of orders by agency.

If you want to group count and orders simultaneously you have to define your own collector, e.g.

```
Map<String, int[]> grouped = ticketOrders
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TicketSale::getAgencyCode,
                                 Collector.of(
                                     () -> new int[2],
                                     (a, t) -> { a[0] += 1; a[1] += t.getTicketsSold(); },
                                     (a, b) -> { a[0] += b[0]; a[1] += b[1]; return a; })));
```

However, this kind of lambdaism might be hard to understand. :-)

[edit]
The collector is composed of three parts in this case.
The first line is the *supplier* that creates a new result container, in this case an array with two elements: one for the count, one for the sum.
The second line is the *accumulator*; it adds data to an existing result container.
The third line is the *combiner* that is used to merge two result containers into one.

For a detailed explanation you might, as always, consult the [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

Comment: The `a -> a` argument can be omitted, to make use of the shorter Collector.of method.

Comment: Thanks VGR, removed it.

Comment: Aventurin, can you possibly explain all of that good stuff you put inside the Collector.of() brackets? I'm very new to both streams and lambdas and have only a very poor idea of what you're doing. I find the syntax puzzling to say the least. I won't ask you to explain the entirety of streams and lambdas to me but if you could state what each of the last three lines actually do in standard English, I think that would be very helpful. I'm going to actually try this code while I'm waiting on your reply to see if I can trace it and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use [`Collectors.summarizingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> salesByAgency
     = ticketOrders.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TicketSale::getAgencyCode,
                 Collectors.summarizingInt(TicketSale::getTicketsSold)));
```

The [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class maintains count, sum, min and max values. So after this you can get the sum for some group:

```
long sum = salesByAgency.get(agencyCode).getSum();
```

But you can also get the count:

```
long count = salesByAgency.get(agencyCode).getCount();
```